# Extract job in BigQuery API - no job configuration object found

Tags: google-bigquery, extract, jobs

I have made an extract object to pass into BigQuery but it does not recognise it via the API.  However, if I paste the JSON object:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "extract": {
      "sourceTable": {
        "datasetId": "data",
        "projectId": "xxxxx",
        "tableId": "s_cus_xxxx_sub_xxxxx_20160301"
      },
      "destinationUris": [
        "gs:\/\/xxxxx\/big-query-extract-20160309234218-*.csv"
      ],
      "printHeader": true,
      "fieldDelimiter": ",",
      "destinationFormat": "CSV",
      "compression": "NONE"
    }
  }
}
```

...into the [online tester](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert), the job completes.

Can anyone see why this does not work via my API call?  Here is my request (with auth token obscured)

```
Request: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/gwt-download/jobs/

-> POST /upload/bigquery/v2/projects/gwt-download/jobs/ HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www.googleapis.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.3 httr/1.0.0 googleAuthR/0.1.2 (gzip)
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip
-> Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX
-> Content-Length: 328
-> 
>> {"configuration":{"extract":{"sourceTable":{"datasetId":"data","projectId":"gwt-download","tableId":"s_cus_7zGNyKAXKX2pIf_sub_7zGNgXl1IQKRls_20160301"},"destinationUris":["gs://big-query-r-extracts/big-query-extract-20160309234218-*.csv"],"printHeader":true,"fieldDelimiter":",","destinationFormat":"CSV","compression":"NONE"}}}

<- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<- X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UrmOHKfqva26g5PgMaWHrkzodVERv3OBk1zOLLnrNY_SGJIEWXrT8J4fYstAJ4stnVEnZMP77DQa0wwxemjPYfNR9mtsw
<- Vary: Origin
<- Vary: X-Origin
<- Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<- Content-Length: 436
<- Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 22:42:19 GMT
<- Server: UploadServer
<- Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
<- Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="31,30,29,28,27,26,25"
<-
```

Error reads:

```
Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0:
```

Comment: It looks like the start of your call has a part twice `{"configuration":{"extract":{"sourceTable":    {'.

Comment: ack sorry that was me trying to prettify the JSON, I've put it in its original form now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-paste error, I was using an upload URL...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/gwt-download/jobs/
```

instead of:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gwt-download/jobs/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem generating the same error is when your headers are not `Content-Type: application/json`